# Rails 5 tests take a long time to complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have recently started an online course using rails 5 and have come to the first set of testing, fairly simple controller tests to assert_response :success.  Having done this exact same course using version 4.2+ I was familiar with the steps involved and thought at such an early stage I would have no problems, however, I have come a cross a timing anomaly I am at a loss to explain.  I have managed to limit my tests to a single test as follows:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should get home" do
    get static_pages_home_url
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Now when I run this test and use the linux 'time' command, I get the following output:

```
$ time rails t
Started with run options --seed 30416

  1/1: [======================================================================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.57486s
1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips


real    0m54.645s
user    0m3.583s
sys     0m0.507s
```

Here you can clearly see that the actual test takes just over half a second, whereas the entire test completed after 54.6 seconds.

Is anyone able to advise what I need to change to have the test complete once the test requested is done?

If there is any additional information you would like me to supply to assist, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Okee dokee then ... I have found the cause and a work-around which gets me back to practicing ￼

The problem stems from the addition of the following to my Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
#   gem 'guard-minitest',         '2.4.4'
end
```

The commented out line for guard-minitest has all my tests returning immediately after they are completed ￼ I have noted that on the [github](https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest) site
related to the gem that there is mention of some issues and although I tried the suggested solution, I was not able to overcome the extra time issue.

As I do not intend to use guard this is a non-issue for me at the moment but I will continue to follow the solutions to see if I can update this question when a solution exists ￼